# implementation of tab bar programmatically not in the rootView

Tags: iphone, ios, xcode, uitabbarcontroller, tabbar

I asked the same question before for the some but now i changed the way to implement my tab bar i have this view

[image: Second view]

i want when i push a button it will make a tab bar composed in 5 buttons the some that i can choose it in the first view

```
    - (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:(NSDictionary *)launchOptions
{
    self.window = [[[UIWindow alloc] initWithFrame:[[UIScreen mainScreen] bounds]] autorelease];
    // Override point for customization after application launch.
    AcceuilViewController *viewController =[[[AcceuilViewController alloc]
                                             initWithNibName:@"AcceuilViewController" bundle:nil]autorelease];
    self.navController = [[[UINavigationController alloc]initWithRootViewController:viewController]
                         autorelease];
   self.window.rootViewController = self.navController;
    [self.window makeKeyAndVisible];
    return YES;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Create your UITabBarController as per normal. When a user touches a button, push to that controller:

```
YourTabController *tabController = [[YourTabController alloc] initWithNibName:@"Tabs" bundle:nil];
[self.navController pushViewController:tabController animated:YES];
```